# Move files in SSIS package as multiple of n

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

How we can execute an SSIS package inside the c# application.

I'm processing bulk files from a shared folder. Instead of doing all in once what I need is that process first n files and do the files related process. Delete that processed files. Check the folder contains files, If yes do the same. It will continue for all the files got processed.

I'm not sure we can implement all the logic inside the SSIS. So I created a SSIS package and inside that, file related process (like source to destination transformation) will do. And in c# console or something else will loop the files batch wise and will call the SSIS package. Any one help me on this ?

Comment: Why do you need to have this loop in c# instead of SSIS? There is no reason that SSIS can't process all files in a folder.

Comment: When doing all files inside the SSIS package using foreach loop getting some memory issues(memory leak). So to try another flow instead of processing all need to process batch wise(Take first n files then process and next n files and process and continue). I'm not sure this logic can achieve inside SSIS package ?

Comment: Anything you can do in C#, you can do in SSIS. The warnings about memory leaks with SSIS are generally related to having it run in an infinite loop watching a folder for file activity. And honestly, that's a scenario I've never tested but it seems questionable at this point in the product lifecycle

Comment: @billinkc anything??? asynchronous processing comes to mind.

Comment: If you have the console app already running, consider an ActionBlock where you use a SQL statement to run the SSIS package. Make sure that the SQL waits for the SSIS package to complete before returning. Also, you can set MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5, which will not batch in 5's but keep 5 running constantly.

Comment: @keithL Could you please give one sample code for waiting the SSIS execution completion.

Comment: I typically reference this website (it is definitely not mine) https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2016/11/28/a-better-way-to-execute-ssis-packages-with-t-sql/

Comment: you can also update package parameters as i am guessing you will need to send in a file path or something to the SSIS package. You will have to look up the correct @objectType